# Delete rows in VBA dependent on value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on a vba project and i'm stuck on (what is essentially) the first part.

I need to delete all rows from my dataset which contain the text 'False' in column I

The reason for not doing this with a filter and delete rows is that i'm automating a report for others and would like the whole report generation to take place with one click of a button.

The code below is as far as i've got, it compiles without any errors...but doesn't seem to actually do anything.

Quick note, there are other sheets that contain formulas referring to this sheet, and it is part of a larger program so i can't afford to delete the sheet and only paste the 'valid' data there

```
Option Explicit

Sub Remfal()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

   Set ws1 = Sheets("Dataset")

   With ws1

    Firstrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlDown).Row
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        With .Cells(Lrow, "I")

            If .Value = "False" Then .EntireRow.Delete

        End With
    Next Lrow
   End With
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple of things to clean up.

```
Sub Remfal()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

    With ws1

        Firstrow = .Cells(1, "I").End(xlDown).Row 'Notice the "." in front of Cells; also i start at I1 and go down (may not be what you want), rather than start at bottom and go down
        Lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

        With ws1.Cells(Lrow, "I") 'You cant "With" within a "With" statement reliably in VBA; instead I closed the old statement and opened a new one

            If .Formula = False Then 'Using .Formula instead of .Value avoids picking up blank values as FALSE; also changed "False" to False, as its a boolean value not text

                .EntireRow.Delete
            End If

        End With
    Next Lrow

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: From what I gather he actually does want to test for the value 'false'

Comment: In that case @ELs I recommend not using the Text "False"; either use the boolean value FALSE, or create a new text-string to compare to; it is not good practice to create a duplicate term like that.

Comment: The data which this is referencing is an externally provided report (which i have no control over) where the value is set to 'False'. As the scope of this project is that a user can paste this data in and then run the master command (which this is part of), changing the values on the export manually is out of scope

Comment: @ELs Fair enough - You can then just put "" around False and it should work as expected; I've tested and confirmed. Just note that I had to make assumptions about where you wanted to start; as David pointed out, you may just want startrow to be row 1, unless you have the word False in there before you actually want to start checking and deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Your FirstRow is wrong, that's why. You start at the last row and try to go down. It doesn't work! Try giving the first row a code name and using that instead! Ex. If you call it FirstRow:

```
FirstRow = Sheet1.Range("FirstRow").Row
```

To make sure you are using the right values, write

```
debug.print firstrow & " " & lastrow
```

After setting the values.

I'm not sure why you want to find the first row because usually users start at the top. Unless there are some 'false' values that you want to overlook in column I, just set the range from 1 to the last row.

Also, as well as setting application.screenupdating = false, I suggest you set Calculation to xlManual and put it back to xlAutomatic at the end. It will help greatly if you have formulas in your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need "With" statement to edit only one defined sheet.

```
Sub Remfal()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Dataset")
Firstrow = ws1.Range("I1").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow = Lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row 'edit before Grade report
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
    If ws1.Cells(Lrow, "I").Value = "False" Then ws1.Cells(Lrow, "I").EntireRow.Delete
Next Lrow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code makes a couple of other unexplained changes which may not produce the desired result. For example, Lastrow will be incorrect if the cells are not continuously filled from I1 to the end of the data in column I. ie: if there's an empty cell in I5, but data in I10, lastrow will be defined only as row 5. Note also that simply removing a With statement is more coding preference than a problem here.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, right for the 1th reports, I changed the result. but I'm not sure for the 2th.

Comment: Well also note that ws1.Range("I1").End(xlUp).Row is the same as just ws1.Range("I1") - but that might not be where OP wants to actually start his data.